# Windows 11 - File Explorer - Right Click menu with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-11

I don't know how I made the extra letters show up here. I was right clicking and double right clicking but it isn't consistent.

**How do I make this menu show up? And what is it?**

[image]

Comment: Are you using a special/old/new version of file explorer?  I can get the C+M boxes to appear by hitting the alt key after right clicking the drive, but none of the others will show.  Also, my copy and modify icons are at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: @Scigrapher no, I am using win 11 pro. I didn't do any modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can trigger them with, anytime you right click, press Alt(left) on keyboard. Usually it'll show all letters, or should show.

However, this is action you get by using Right Mouse Button on keyboard (https://community.adobe.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/223779i292EAFC4C79BCD4B?v=v2) ...image will clarify

Answer (score 1):

The menu you are using is a true Context menu, with some of items like Paste are a a direct context of Copy.

The extra letters are not part of the context menu. I am not sure how they got there for you, but they are not part of Context. In Excel they grey letters show up with the Alt Key.

To see all the context items, select More Options.

I find the main context menu is fine for most things, and More Options is not used that often.

So what you see is totally normal (without the letters).